# How Can I Copy files to a Mounted Drive using AppleScript?

Tags: applescript

In what way can I copy home folders (Documents, Pictures, Movies, etc...) to a mounted drive **without** using the **POSIX function** in AppleScript?

Answer (score 1):

### Finder

```
tell application "Finder"
    duplicate items of home to disk "WD" with exact copy
end tell
```

`with exact copy` preserves owner and group, like Paste Exactly.

### cp

```
do shell script "cp -a ~/ /Volumes/WD"
```

`cp -a` is equivalent to `cp -Rp`. `-p` preserves times, mode, owner and group, extended attributes, ACLs, file flags, and resource forks.

### rsync

```
do shell script "rsync -aE ~/ /Volumes/WD"
```

`-E` preserves extended attributes, ACLs, file flags, and resource forks.

Comment: Using the shell script method. How would I tell applescript to copy from a folder to the /Volumes/WD?